# "How can I get the URL parameters on my landing page <a link='?example=id'> attribute"

Tags: javascript, html, string, url, hyperlink

"I am using a landing page https://example.com/?ad={{ad_set}} I was trying to get the URL parameter on a link that I am using on my landing page in the format of https://example.com/?ad={{ad_set}}'>

Can anyone have any advice on how can I pass the URL string value on the landing page link attribute? "

Comment: Hi. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you trying to grab the `ad_set` value from the URL programmatically?

Comment: @Nomz I need to add this value in link attribute <a href='https://example2.com/?parameter={HERE-I-WANT-TO-GET}'

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query parameters of the URL using

```
window.location.search.substring(1);
```

It will return all the value after '?' from the URL.

Or if you want a specific value, you can even use (referencing the example of URL you mentioned: https://example.com/?ad=123)

```
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
urlParams.get('ad');
```

It will return 123.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I am using the <a href='https://example.com/?ad=[how-can-i-get-same-value-of-ad-parameter-here]'>example.com</a>

Comment: So, basically, you want information about the complete URL param? Or just the query params?

Comment: `window.location.pathname` will return the path and filename to the current page.